# pixel size across devices

Tags: css, responsive-design

Many front-end definitions in CSS use pixels as their measure. When designing for multiple display sizes, how is that a relevant measure? I assume the pixel size is a function of the display resolution. Is there any way to use real sizes (e.g. millimeters or likewise), or how does it really make sense to use pixels as a measure given the great variance in screen resolutions in the wild?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Font-relative lengths:** the ‘[**em**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#em-unit)’, ‘[**ex**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#ex-unit)’, ‘[**ch**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#ch-unit)’, ‘[**rem**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#rem-unit)’ units

**Viewport-percentage lengths:** the ‘[**vw**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#vw-unit)’, ‘[**vh**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#vh-unit)’, ‘[**vmin**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#vmin-unit)’, ‘[**vmax**](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#vmax-unit)’ units

**Absolute lengths:** the ‘cm’, ‘mm’, ‘in’, ‘pt’, ‘pc’, ‘px’ units

<sub>Note, not all of these lengths are fully supported across browsers. See http://caniuse.com/viewport-units</sub>

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/

---

Absolute lengths, such as `px` are often used in media queries for responsive design, along side with a viewport tag set such as `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">`. This can help target screen resolutions.

Viewport percentage based lengths are probably the most optimal length, however they are [**not fully supported**](http://caniuse.com/viewport-units) throughout all browsers; therefore they may not be your best option.

Comment: Any good search query for finding what's supported across browsers?

Comment: @matt Yep! See http://caniuse.com/viewport-units tons of helpful charts for cross browser support.

Comment: Thanks! I know it's not directly related, but what's the best way to get the screen dimensions, that's standard across most browsers while at it? actually it's very related

Comment: @matt So long as you have a viewport set with `content="width=device-width"`, you can target device screen dimensions with absolute px. **[See this](http://www.mobitest.me/devices/)** for common device dimensions. The breakpoints I usually use are found **[in this answer of mine.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18814930/what-are-the-common-media-queries-when-building-responsive-site/18814981#18814981)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use several types of units take a look at the [W3C CSS units](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).